# Product Recommendations

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I'm looking for an inkjet printer that can print large numbers of envelopes.

Is there anywhere on the SE network that I can ask that question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Contrary to what [Popular Demand](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70064/product-recommendations/70065#70065) says, I'm pretty sure this is a Super User question.

Comment: I guess I'll try it and see what happens.

Comment: @SLaks, that's what I would do.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/210165/can-inkjet-printers-print-envelopes

Comment: It's a Super User question as long as it isn't a shopping recommendation. Basically, instead of focusing on getting a list of options, try stating your need and discovering whether such a device exists (which I think was done well enough by @SLaks just now). Something like [the physical equivalent of polling for app recommendations](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67608/where-to-ask-about-app-recommendations/67610#67610).

Answer (score 4):

No. Stack Exchange doesn't do product recommendations of any kind; they're a subset of "list of X" questions.

Comment: This isn't quite that; I'm not sure if such a printer exists.  If I convert it to `Are there any inkjet printers that can print envelopes in bulk?`, would it fit on SU?

Comment: It does support recommendations more recently, but software-specific https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/