# Is there a way to solicit 'recipes'?

Tags: discussion

I'm a Ruby on Rails developer. I have two pieces of functionality I'd like to accomplish via a Gem. Say I have three Gem choices for one piece, and seven Gem choices for the other piece. I'd like to solicit recommended combinations that are known to work well together in accomplishing the functionalities.

Is there a way to accomplish this without running afoul of basic posting guidelines?

I'm afraid it would be considered 'solicitation of opinion'?

For example:

I'm building a Ruby on Rails application that is very forms-centric, AND has a very state based application workflow , i.e. a submission can be in one of 13 states, 'submitted', 'cleared' .... 'bound','policy issued'.  The processing of these states is complex.

So I would like to find a good combination of a forms Gem and a state machine Gem.

So far I've looked at Formtastic and ActiveAdmin for the Forms. Either one would work for me.

I used `acts_as_state_machine` in a prototype years ago, and it looks like it was renamed to AASM.

Now I find

```
state_machine
AASM
state_manager
ragel
Simple State Machine
....
```

Is there a recommended combination of the forms and state machine Gems?

Comment: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @PeterMortensen Closing posts [does not bump them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48578/what-can-cause-a-question-to-be-bumped).

Answer (score 3):

Best practices questions occupy a grey area on SE. Phrasing is important. Phrasing your question as "I want to do X, and I tried Y, but that wasn't sufficient. How can I accomplish this?" is good. But if your question is more phrased like shopping or fishing for opinions or discussions, then it will likely be closed.

Basically, your questions should ideally have answers that are close to objective on the objective/subjective spectrum. If that's impossible, then it shouldn't be asked anywhere. There isn't really a trilogy site that tolerates opinion much more than the others.

See also [Where to ask about app recommendations?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67608/where-to-ask-about-app-recommendations)

And [What can we do about questions asking for plugin/script recommendations?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94132/what-can-we-do-about-questions-asking-for-plugin-script-recommendations)

As for the example in the OP... I would lean toward vote to close, especially because there are multiple answers. But meta still doesn't seem to have chosen a firm stance on library recommendations.

If you were asking for the differences between two libraries, that might be one way to keep it alive. And then you could decide for yourself based on the merits of the comparison..

Comment: I usually vote to close questions that are generally "how can I accomplish this broad task" but I often tell the person why so they have a chance to improve.